# sql 2005 - trace capturing all events

Tags: sql-server-2005, profiler

I am trying to capture all statements/SPs and RPCs (either they finish or fail) on a SQL 2005 server using SQL trace.
Are the following events enough?

```
Exceptions
Stored Procedure
RPC:Completed
RPC:Starting
SP:Recompile
TSQL
SQL:StmtCompleted
SQL:StmtStarting
```

thanks!

Comment: You may also want to capture the SQL:BatchStarting and SQL:BatchCompleted events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a trace template.  Click File, New Trace, and choose the Replay template.  That'll get you everything that happens.